# GridPagerAdapter and CardFragment Update When Shown

Tags: android, android-fragments, visibility, wear-os, android-pageradapter

I am using a custom `GridPagerAdapter` and `CardFragment` on the wearable. The `CardFragment` has a `TextView` that uses the `android:ellipsize` attribute set to `marquee`. The `TextView` does not scroll until `setSelected(true)` is called on it. The problem I am having is where to put that method call so that the text will only scroll when the card is in view. Right now I call the `setSelected()` method in the `onCreateContentView()` of the `CardFragment`, but this makes it so that the text is always selected, and scrolls even when the card is not in view.

I have looked through the documentation for both [`GridPagerAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/GridPagerAdapter.html) and [`CardFragment`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/CardFragment.html), but I do not see a method that would suit my needs. I have tried the `CardFragment` methods `onHiddenChanged()`, `onStart()`/`onStop()` and `onResume()`/`onPause()`. `onHiddenChanged()` does not seem to get called at all. `onPause()` and `onStop()` seem to work as expected, but `onStart()` and `onResume()` get called before the fragment is actually in view. Is it possible to know when the card is actually in view (and when it is hidden), or am I out of luck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, adapters just provide data, whereas the views that use them actually determine when to display it. Thus, I think you need to go directly to the `GridViewPager` and add a [`GridViewPager.OnPageChangeListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/GridViewPager.OnPageChangeListener.html). That way you can listen for when the page is added and call `setSelected()` then.

Comment: Thank you, this works perfectly. Though I did have to call `onPageSelected()` manually on the first page in `setContentView()` because it was not called automatically.